# ERD Database Management

Tags: database-design, erd

IS this correct?

The purpose of this database is to keep track of books and sold and rented and donated at Reeeding Rino’s. We are a small used book store that specializes in old books. We have a special feature that allows our customers to rent books, as well as trade in old owned books for books in stock. So someone can bring in a book they own and give it to us and in return purchase a book at equal or less value of the one they have brought in.

This DB will allow us to track what books we have in stock as well as what books are donated, traded and rented. I am leaving out any debt owed on overdue books to make things easier.  So this DB should give us reports on how many books are out in house, rented, overdue and donated, along with a customer profile telling us what each customer has either rented, bought or donated in the past, so we can suggest books they enjoy. I want to be able to create a mailing list with book suggestions from in stock books.

Business Rules:

Customer-Book
One Customer can be rent or purchase or donate Many Books (M)
One Book can be rent or purchase or donated by Many Customers (M)
Customer [M:N] Book.

Customer-Rent (Associative)
One Customer can rent Many Rental (M)
One Rental can be rented by Many Customer (M) (one at time)
Customer-Rent [M:N]

Customer-Donate (Associative)
One Customer can donate Many Rental (M)
One Rental can be donated by Many Customer (M) (one at time)
Customer-Rent [M:N]

Customer-Purchase (Associative)
One Customer can have Many Purchases (M)
One Purchase can have by  One Customer (1) 
Customer-Rent [M:1]